# Numba - how to return multiple columns ( arrays) - after group by apply

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, numba, pandas-apply

I would like to run groupby and then apply Numba function on top of a pandas.
This is the example :

```
@nb.jit(nopython=True) 
def my_Numba_function(arr1,arr2):    
    arr1[:] =11
    arr2[:] =22

    return arr1,arr2    

and_df= df_input_imputed.groupby(key_cols_list, as_index = True)[['col_1,'col_2']].\
    apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(my_Numba_function(arr1 = x['col_1'].values,arr2 = x['col_2'].values)) )
```

And instead of getting two columns additional to my index, I am getting the results in a lot of columns ( rows became columns).

[image]

How can I fix this ?

Thanks,
Boris

Comment: It is not clear to me what you want to do with the magic oneliner (that is poorly parsed by S.O. parsers). Does this help: https://tedboy.github.io/pandas/enhancingperf/enhancingperf2.html . By the way, please do not provide dataframes as image but text and if possible one that can be imported with Pandas via `pd.read_clipboard`.

Comment: would like to run groupby + apply , when the returning two columns ( from my_Numba_function). 

and then having this two columns part of my dataframe.


In my example above I am getting a lot of new columns instead of just two .